# iOS: Augmented reality framework around for iOS

Tags: ios

I would like to develop an Augmented reality app for iOS and Android, for showing location based fuel stations, pharmacies etc. I am trying to get a free framework which is the best product around to integrate and develop with my iOS app. I heard about several sdk's metaio.com/products, QuickBlox/ChattAR-ios etc. Could someone please advise which one is the best provider for all at free and I should go with?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: For [various reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/158468), questions like this one asking for "the best X" aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow. You might be able to rephrase it to avoid that, like: "here's my problem... how can I solve it?"

Comment: 'Shopping list' questions are generally not accepted here. You might try editing your question to make it more *objective*, rather than *subjective*.

Comment: personally I find 'shopping list' questions very useful. From the clash of opinions emerges the truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ia a nice AR framework: [iPhone ARKit](https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/)

Hope it helps you.